# jquery is not working in a master page

Tags: javascript

I am update date and time in lable control show it master page.

I have no issues when doing using JQuery in a aspx page without a

masterpage, but when I try to use it in pages that have a masterpage, it doesn't work,

here is my code is

```
    function DateTime()
    {
        window.setTimeout("DateTime()", 1000);

        var TD = new Date();

        document.getElementById("Label2").innerHTML = TD.toLocaleString('en-GB');
    }
```

Comment: may be you are writing this code in head and label2 is not render. just wrap the code with onload function or jQuery's ready function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use chrome F12  find error...
use DateTime() on master page in the end

Comment: i mean,may be you are writing this code in head and label2 is not render. just wrap the code with onload function or jQuery's ready function

Comment: <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DateTime() {
            window.setTimeout("DateTime()", 1000);
            var TD = new Date();

            document.getElementById("Label2").innerHTML = TD.toLocaleString('en-GB');
        }
    </script>

            document.getElementById("Label2").innerHTML = TD.toLocaleString('en-GB');
        }
    </script>    <body onload="DateTime()"> <asp:Label ID="Label2" ForeColor="White" runat="server"></asp:Label>

Comment: document.getElementById("<%=Label2.ClinetID%>")

Comment: Thanks sir a lot of  i am searching this problems for two week . again thanks very much. may i know name plz

Answer (score 0):

You're not really using jQuery here. But that code should do what you want:

```
$(function() {
    var TD = new Date();
    $('#Label2').html(TD.toLocaleString('en-GB'));
});
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function DateTime() {
            window.setTimeout("DateTime()", 1000);
            var TD = new Date();

            document.getElementById("Label2").innerHTML = TD.toLocaleString('en-GB');
        }
    </script>

Comment: show it master page in a label control using it javascript what is problems plz cheque